# String path displayed when adding Image in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, imageicon

I tried using setValueAt in adding an image but the problem is it prints the string and does not load the image.  any help on this. the code is below

```
int selectedColumn = table1.getSelectedColumn();
int selectedRow = table1.getSelectedRow();
ImageIcon addIcon = new ImageIcon("c:\\onion.png");
table1.getModel().setValueAt(addIcon, selectedRow, electedColumn);
```

Comment: Can you post your code of how you're creating your JTable?

Answer (score 4):

You need to [create a table model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) which returns `Icon.class` for its [`getColumnClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#getColumnClass%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your table knows what data is stored in a given column so it can choose the appropriate renderer. So, your JTable creation code should be something like this:

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(dataObject, columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel){
    public Class getColumnClass(int column){
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }
};
```

Comment: yes, overridding getColumnClass is the right thing todo in most contexts - but a) should be done by the model (_not_ by the table) b) doing it by actual value is a bit risky, must at least guard against null